# WCF - looking for best practice when having multiple contracts sharing common methods

Tags: c#, wcf

I intend to have one core module exposing interfaces so that other big modules (different clients) will communicate with. If, say, there are group of methods:

```
void Method_A();
void Method_B();
void Method_X1();
```

to expose to one type of clients (module "X1") and:

```
void Method_A();
void Method_B();
void Method_X2();
```

to expose to other type of clients (module "X2") and knowing that `Method_A` and `Method_B` should have the exact implementation ... then how can I best design the service(s) architecture (in terms of services and contracts) ?

Is there any chance to implement Method_A and Method_B only once (not 2 times in different contract implementations)?

How shall I benefit of interface inheritance when using WCF ?

Thank you all in advance and please let me know if I need to make it more clear!

@marc_s... I would really appreciate your point of view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes can inherit the methods that satisfy an interface, so you could have a `IServiceBase` interface and `ServiceBase` class that just implements `Method_A` and `Method_B`, then single out the unique methods into separate interfaces, finally combining them together in classes that inherit `ServiceBase` and implement either Interface1 or Interface2. eg:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceBase
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Method_A();

    [OperationContract]
    void Method_B();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1 : IServiceBase
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Method_X1();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService2 : IServiceBase
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Method_X2();
}

public abstract class ServiceBase : IServiceBase
{
    void Method_A()
    {
        ... implementation here ...
    }

    void Method_B()
    {
        ... implementation here ...
    }
}

public class Service1 : ServiceBase, IService1
{
    void Method_X1()
    {
        ... implementation here ...
    }
}

public class Service2 : ServiceBase, IService2
{
    void Method_X2()
    {
        ... implementation here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really good... Thank you ... I will give it a try and come back to you

Comment: To be honest, for the given scenario your solution is good. I am just trying to figure out what solution is best and flexible when going for real world applications... How would you compare your solution to marc's ? Whatever thoughts you have in mind... put them in writing, thank you!

Comment: I accept your answer since is correct and might help other people. But I wanted more a point of view on things, than a solution. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've been called!?!?! :-)

If you have one interface

```
public interface IServiceA
{
  void Method_A();
  void Method_B();
  void Method_X1();
}
```

and a second one

```
public interface IServiceB
{
  void Method_A();
  void Method_B();
  void Method_X2();
}
```

you can absolutely share the implementation code for the two common methods on the server side.

You'd create two classes `MethodAHandler` and `MethodBHandler` on your server, in a common class library (or in two separate, common assemblies), and then you could use something like:

```
using MethodHandlers;  // contains the two method handlers

public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
   public void Method_A()
   {
       MethodAHandler hnd = new MethodAHandler();
       hnd.HandleMethodCall();
   }

   public void Method_B()
   {
       MethodBHandler hnd = new MethodBHandler();
       hnd.HandleMethodCall();
   }

   public void Method_X1()
   {
       // handle method X1 call here or delegate to another handler class
   }
}
```

and for the second service:

```
using MethodHandlers;  // contains the two method handlers

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
   public void Method_A()
   {
       MethodAHandler hnd = new MethodAHandler();
       hnd.HandleMethodCall();
   }

   public void Method_B()
   {
       MethodBHandler hnd = new MethodBHandler();
       hnd.HandleMethodCall();
   }

   public void Method_X2()
   {
       // handle method X2 call here or delegate to another handler class
   }
}
```

On the server side, you have .NET classes and you can absolutely share code between two separate service implementation by means of a common class library or whatever you find the best approach for you.

Comment: Hi Marc. Very nice and complete answer... I really respect you! I find your answer much more flexible (in case even 'A' & 'B' methods will not be common anymore). How would you comment "C. Lawrence Wenham" approach with the abstract class? Pros & cons? ... Thank you!

Comment: Somehow I like this idea of inheritance... Do you opt for not using inheritance? What are your thoughts?